# SOLR admin console in solr.war of IBM WCS 7

Tags: solr, websphere-commerce, commerce, wcs

I would like to debug how solr will internally makes call to its component when we make any call to it by passing a search team in below way

```
solr/MC_10001_CatalogEntry_en_US/select?q=*:*&fq=defaultSearch:"red"
```

It looks like using solr admin console we can debug calls very good. but in OOB IBM provided jar admin console of SOLR is not included. so we need to download Apache solr version of solr.war and extract only those files needed for admin console and form .war with IBM WAR and deploy back to server.

Any one knows the exact process and files needs to be moved? Any links for the same is greatly appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you already find an answer, anyway I'll post it.
WCS InfoCenter describes the steps to follow in order to integrate the admin UI files in the solr-search web app:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.developer.doc/concepts/csdsearchperf.htm?lang=en

However it has few errors also reported in the IC page's comments. So I'll describe the steps here, valid for FEP7 Toolkit version:

1) Download the SOLR version 4.3.0 from: http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/4.3.0/

2) Unzip solr-4.3.0.zip

3) Copy the following directories and files from the unzip folder into the Search-Solr/WebContent directory:
        css
        img
        js
        tpl
        admin.html
        favicon.ico

4) Open the Search-Solr\WebContent\WEB-INF\ibm-web-ext.xml file for editing.

5) Find the enable-file-serving flag and set it to true.

```
For example, in bold:

<web-ext
   xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-ext_1_0.xsd"
   version="1.0">

   <reload-interval value="3"/>
   <context-root uri="/solr" />
   <enable-directory-browsing value="false"/>
   <enable-file-serving value="true"/>
   <enable-reloading value="false"/>
   <enable-serving-servlets-by-class-name value="false" />

</web-ext>
```

6) Save your changes and close the file.

7) Deploy the Search-Solr project; Right-click the project and select Java EE > Prepare for Deployment.

8) Update the following files:
        Search-Solr\WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml

9) Change the URL pattern for the SolrSearchServlet servlet to /Search-Solr.
    For example:

```
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>SolrSearchServlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/Search-Solr</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

10) Save your changes and close the files.

11) Publish the search EAR.

hope you can find it useful.
good luck
Francesco